# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un enum a un objeto concreto de un arrayList de objetos con el siguiente código?

Tags: java, poo, funciones

Dejo aqui el ejercicio completo por si podeís ayudarme con mas partes y muchas gracias de antemano

Una tienda de vehículos de ocasión nos ha pedido programar parte de su web. Debemos gestionar 2 tipos de vehículos: coches y furgonetas. Utiliza para ello una estructura dinámica.
Los atributos de todos los vehículos son: matricula, numKilometros.
Los coches tienen el atributo propiedad que podrá tomar como valores propio o alquilado.
**Las furgonetas tendrán el atributo tonelaje que tomará únicamente los valores: Dos Toneladas, Tres Toneladas o Cuatro Toneladas. Dicho tonelaje deberá ser especificado al añadir cada furgoneta al ArrayList a partir de un menú**(Ver ejemplo compilado)
Muestra el total de kilómetros de todos los vehículos. A continuación elimina aquellos que tengan el mismo número de kilómetros y vuelve a mostrar el total de kilómetros de todos los vehículos.
Al final del programa ofrece la posibilidad de listar por atributo de forma descendente al listado anterior mostrado:

1. Por matrícula.
2. Por número de kilómetros.

Vuelca dicha información listada a un fichero de salida con ruta absoluta al escritorio.
Controla 2 excepciones del sistema añadiendo con comentarios que realiza.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejVehiculosOcasion {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Se crea un ArrayList para guardar objetos de tipo Coche.
    static ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList();

    //metodo kmTotales 
    public static void kmTotales(ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos){

        for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.size(); i++) {
            kmTotales = kmTotales+vehiculos.get(i).getNumKilometros();
        }
            System.out.println(kmTotales);
    }
    //método main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nFurgoneta = 0, opcionFurgo = 0;

        vehiculos.add(new Coche("5543HTX", 50000.9, Propiedad.propio));
        vehiculos.add(new Coche("5678GWX", 72300.5, Propiedad.alquilado));
        vehiculos.add(new Coche("1414LLL", 8300.0, Propiedad.alquilado));
        vehiculos.add(new Coche("1234RTX", 50000.9, Propiedad.propio));

        do {
            
            System.out.println("Elija opción de zona de carga para la furgoneta: " + nFurgoneta);
            System.out.println("1. Dos toneladas.");
            System.out.println("2: Tres toneladas.");
            System.out.println("3: Cuatro toneladas.");
            opcionFurgo = sc.nextInt();
            
            //Esta es la parte que no se editar para que las furgonetas de 
            //abajo se creen segun la opcion 
            switch(opcionFurgo){
            //crea la furgoneta con esos tonelajes segun la opcion
                case 1:
                    nFurgoneta++;
                    break;
                case 2:                    
                    nFurgoneta++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    nFurgoneta++;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                    break;
            }
            //crea la furgoneta si nFurgoneta = 1/2/3
            //Estas furgonetas son las que deben tener el kilometraje
            if (opcionFurgo==1) {
                vehiculos.add(new Furgoneta("3456FGN", 220000.0,Tonelaje.Cuatro_Toneladas));
            }else if(opcionFurgo==2){
                vehiculos.add(new Furgoneta("3487FGN", 220000.0,Tonelaje.Dos_Toneladas));
            }else{
                vehiculos.add(new Furgoneta("8282JGN", 131500.7,Tonelaje.Dos_Toneladas));
            }
            
        } while (nFurgoneta < 3);

        kmTotales(vehiculos);
        
    } //fin método main

}



//Aqui pongo la Clase Vehiculo y los hijos
public class Vehiculo{
    
    //ATRIBUTOS
    // matricula / numKilometros /
    private String matricula;
    private double numKilometros;
    
    
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Vehiculo(String matricula, double numKilometros){
    
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.numKilometros = numKilometros;
    
    }

    public Vehiculo() {
    }
    
    
    //GETTERS Y SETTERS

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public double getNumKilometros() {
        return numKilometros;
    }

    public void setNumKilometros(int numKilometros) {
        this.numKilometros = numKilometros;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehiculo{" + "matricula=" + matricula + ", numKilometros=" + numKilometros + '}';
    }
    

}
```

**Clases hijos**

```
public class Coche extends Vehiculo{
    
    Propiedad propiedad;

    public Coche(String matricula, double numKilometros, Propiedad propiedad) {
        super(matricula, numKilometros);
        this.propiedad = propiedad;
    }

    public Coche() {
    }
    

    public Propiedad getPropiedad() {
        return propiedad;
    }

    public void setPropiedad(Propiedad propiedad) {
        this.propiedad = propiedad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coche{" + "propiedad=" + propiedad + '}';
    }
    
    
    
}


public class Furgoneta extends Vehiculo{
    
    Tonelaje tonelaje;

    public Furgoneta(String matricula, double numKilometros, Tonelaje tonelaje) {
        super(matricula, numKilometros);
        this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
    }

    public Furgoneta(Tonelaje tonelaje) {
        this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
    }

    public Tonelaje getTonelaje() {
        return tonelaje;
    }

    public void setTonelaje(Tonelaje tonelaje) {
        this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Furgoneta{" + "tonelaje=" + tonelaje + '}';
    }
        
    
}
```

Comment: Hola Alvaro, qué has intentado? Veo que tienes definido el método `public static void kmTotales(ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos)` qué sería lo que no entiendes? Saludos!

Comment: Hola buenas Andrés, lo primero muchas gracias por responderme. Justo ayer por la noche conseguí resolver ese problema. Lo que quería era sumar todos los kilometros de cada vehiculo en el array de objetos. //metodo kmTotales
    public static void kmTotales(ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos){
    
        for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.size(); i++) {
            kmTotales = kmTotales+vehiculos.get(i).getNumKilometros();
        }
        System.out.println(kmTotales);
    }

Comment: Lo que estoy un poco atascado es en como puedo hacer para crear desde el switch las furgonetas con sus respectivos tonelajes. Pues de momento los crea mal, y no consigo ver con que condiciones hacerlo. Perdon si mis preguntas son algo estupidas o por el estilo... estoy muy verde y por problemas de  covid en casa estoy apurado... tengo ya el examen de programacion el lunes. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, si pudiste resolver tu problema inicial, por favor edita tu pregunta con el problema que tienes ahora, asi te podemos ayudar mejor

Comment: Si perdón, soy nuevo aquí y aun no me habitué; Ya lo he cambiado, y señale en el codigo con comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido hacer el ejercicio completo os dejo el código completo aquí por si alguien lo necesita en un futuro.

Clase Principal:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class ejVehiculosOcasion {

    static double kmTotales;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Se crea un ArrayList para guardar objetos de tipo Coche.
    static ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList();

    //metodo kmTotales
    public static void kmTotales(ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos) {

        for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.size(); i++) {
            kmTotales = kmTotales + vehiculos.get(i).getNumKilometros();
        }
        System.out.println(kmTotales);
    }

    //método main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Vlad\\Desktop\\ordenacionVehiculos.txt"));

            int nFurgoneta = 0, opcionFurgo = 0;

            vehiculos.add(new Coche("5543HTX", 50000.9, Propiedad.propio));
            vehiculos.add(new Coche("5678GWX", 72300.5, Propiedad.alquilado));
            vehiculos.add(new Coche("1414LLL", 8300.0, Propiedad.alquilado));
            vehiculos.add(new Coche("1234RTX", 50000.9, Propiedad.propio));

            do {
                Furgoneta furgoneta;
                furgoneta = new Furgoneta();
                System.out.println("Elija opción de zona de carga para la furgoneta: " + nFurgoneta);
                System.out.println("1. Dos toneladas.");
                System.out.println("2: Tres toneladas.");
                System.out.println("3: Cuatro toneladas.");
                opcionFurgo = sc.nextInt();

                switch (opcionFurgo) {
                    //crea la furgoneta con esos tonelajes segun la opcion
                    case 1:
                        furgoneta.setTonelaje(Tonelaje.Dos_Toneladas);
                        nFurgoneta++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        furgoneta.setTonelaje(Tonelaje.Tres_Toneladas);
                        nFurgoneta++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        furgoneta.setTonelaje(Tonelaje.Cuatro_Toneladas);
                        nFurgoneta++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                        break;
                }
                //crea la furgoneta si nFurgoneta == 1/2/3
                if (nFurgoneta == 1) {//actualizando los atributos para cada objeto
                    furgoneta.setMatricula("3456FGN");
                    furgoneta.setNumKilometros(220000.0);
                } else if (opcionFurgo == 2) {
                    furgoneta.setMatricula("3487FGN");
                    furgoneta.setNumKilometros(220000.0);
                } else {
                    furgoneta.setMatricula("8282JGN");
                    furgoneta.setNumKilometros(131500.7);
                }

                vehiculos.add(furgoneta);

            } while (nFurgoneta < 3);

            System.out.println(vehiculos);
            System.out.print("Kilometros totales con duplicados: ");
            kmTotales(vehiculos);

            //arrayList auxiliar sin duplicados de kilometraje
            ArrayList<Double> kilometrajeSinDuplicar = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Vehiculo> arrayObjetosVehiculosSinDuplicar = new ArrayList<>();
            int kmTotalesSinDuplicados = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.size(); i++) {
                //eliminar los vehiculos de kilometros duplicados
                if (!kilometrajeSinDuplicar.contains(vehiculos.get(i).getNumKilometros())) {
                    kilometrajeSinDuplicar.add(vehiculos.get(i).getNumKilometros());
                    kmTotalesSinDuplicados += vehiculos.get(i).getNumKilometros();
                    //Vamos a recuperar tambien los vehiculos que no tengan los duplicados
                    arrayObjetosVehiculosSinDuplicar.add(vehiculos.get(i));
                }

            }

            //mostramos el array de vehiculos sin duplicar
            System.out.println("\nVehiculos sin duplicados: ");
            System.out.println(arrayObjetosVehiculosSinDuplicar);
            System.out.println("Kilometros totales sin duplicados: " + kmTotalesSinDuplicados);

            //menu mostrar por matricula o numero de km de forma descendiente
            int op = 0;

            do {

                System.out.println("Elija opción para listar: ");
                System.out.println("1. Por matrícula.");
                System.out.println("2: Por numero de kilómetros.");
                System.out.println("3: Salir.");
                op = sc.nextInt();

                switch (op) {

                    case 1:
                        Collections.sort(arrayObjetosVehiculosSinDuplicar);
                        System.out.println(arrayObjetosVehiculosSinDuplicar);
                        //No hace falta recorrer pues es un array
                        bw.write(arrayObjetosVehiculosSinDuplicar.toString());
                        bw.newLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //primero hay que ordenar y luego darle la vuelta
                        Collections.sort(kilometrajeSinDuplicar);
                        Collections.reverse(kilometrajeSinDuplicar);
                        System.out.println(kilometrajeSinDuplicar);

                        for (int i = 0; i < kilometrajeSinDuplicar.size(); i++) {
                            bw.write(kilometrajeSinDuplicar.get(i).toString());//siempre casting para escribir en fichero
                            bw.newLine();
                        }
                        
                        /*sino quieres hacerlo por lineas
                        bw.write(vehiculosSinDuplicar.toString());
                        bw.newLine();
                        */
                        
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        op = 3;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opcion no valida");
                        break;
                }
                bw.close();
            } while (op != 3);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {//sino encuentra la ruta del archivo sale el mensaje de error
            System.out.println("No se pudo encontrar la ruta del fichero.");
        } catch (IOException e) { //error mas generales
            System.out.println("No se pudo leer el fichero.");
        }

    } //fin método main

}
```

Clases Objeto Vehiculo:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Vehiculo implements Comparable<Vehiculo> {

    //ATRIBUTOS
    // matricula / numKilometros /
    private String matricula;
    private double numKilometros;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Vehiculo(String matricula, double numKilometros) {

        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.numKilometros = numKilometros;

    }

    public Vehiculo() {
    }

    //GETTERS Y SETTERS
    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public double getNumKilometros() {
        return numKilometros;
    }

    public void setNumKilometros(double numKilometros) {
        this.numKilometros = numKilometros;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vehiculo o) {
        //va a comparar las matriculas
        return matricula.compareTo(o.matricula);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Vehiculo other = (Vehiculo) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.matricula, other.matricula)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "numKilometros";
    }

    
}
```

Clase hijo Coche:

```
public class Coche extends Vehiculo{
    
    Propiedad propiedad;

    public Coche(String matricula, double numKilometros, Propiedad propiedad) {
        super(matricula, numKilometros);
        this.propiedad = propiedad;
    }

    public Coche() {
    }
    
    //GETTERS Y SETTERS
    public Propiedad getPropiedad() {
        return propiedad;
    }

    public void setPropiedad(Propiedad propiedad) {
        this.propiedad = propiedad;
    }

    //METODOS
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coche = "+" Matricula: "+getMatricula() +", Kilometros: "+ getNumKilometros()+ ", propiedad: " + propiedad + "\n";
    }
```

Clase hijo Furgoneta:

```
public class Furgoneta extends Vehiculo {
    //ATRIBUTOS
    Tonelaje tonelaje;

    //CONSTRUCTORES
    public Furgoneta(String matricula, double numKilometros, Tonelaje tonelaje) {
        super(matricula, numKilometros);
        this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
    }
    
    public Furgoneta(String matricula, double numKilometros) {
        super(matricula, numKilometros);
    }
    
    public Furgoneta(Tonelaje tonelaje) {
        this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
    }

    public Furgoneta() {
    }

    //GETTERS Y SETTERS
    
    public Tonelaje getTonelaje() {
        return tonelaje;
    }

    public void setTonelaje(Tonelaje tonelaje) {
        this.tonelaje = tonelaje;
    }

    //METODOS
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Furgoneta = " +" Matricula "+getMatricula()+ ", Kilometros: "+ getNumKilometros()+", tonelaje=" + tonelaje +"\n";
    }  
    
}
```

Enums:

```
public enum Tonelaje {
    Dos_Toneladas, Tres_Toneladas, Cuatro_Toneladas
}

public enum Propiedad {
    propio, alquilado
}
```